# Rate it js. Stars are broken when hovers

Tags: jquery, rateit.js

I was able to implement rateit.js for my rating feature.

It works fine when it comes to backend.

However frontend looks messed up.

[image]

I'm having a hard time to find the issue

Is this something bugs of this library.

I wanted to ask chat gpt. However, it would be best if human answers it.

Here's how the backend

```
<div class="feedback--container">
<div class="feedback__star">
<input type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" step="0.5" id="backing3" name="ratings">
<div class="rateit" data-rateit-backingfld="#backing3" data-rateit-mode="font"  style="font-size:70px">
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="feedback__content">
 <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Enter description.." name="description"> 
 </textarea>
 </div>
 </div>
```

@section('extra-script')

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" 
 {{asset('public/pwa_asset/assets/plugins/rateit/scripts/rateit.css')}}" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('public/pwa_asset/assets/plugins/webfont/webfont.js')}}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('public/pwa_asset/assets/plugins/rateit/scripts/jquery.rateit.min.js')}}"></script>

<script>
    
    $('.card--slider__container').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        centerMode: true,
        variableWidth: true
    });

</script>

 @endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

I added fixes manually on my custom.css

```
 /* Stars */
 .rateit-font .rateit-range > div, .rateit-font .rateit-range > span {
    display:flex !important;
 }
```

It fixed the issue. Looks like it is a bug on rateit.js

[image]